# "x" cannot be invoked without "new"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-modules

currently following a tutorial from the man Brad Traversy about coding an interactive WebApp with node.js and I've run into a problem, that still consists when I paste his github code btw.

```
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session)
```

I'm using connect-mongo to store session data, but the require just doesn't work and it throws this error:

> TypeError: Class constructor MongoStore cannot be invoked without 'new'

could someone help me with a brief explanation and a block of code to fix this, because I've looked through several similar questions on stackoverflow, but didn't really understand it.

Cheers

Comment: Can you give a link to the tutorial

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBvmnHTQIPY 

Timestamp is 1:09 at chapter "Storing sessions"

Comment: As you see in current connect-mongo docs, its usage is changed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo-connect error with mongo-connect(session)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66654037/mongo-connect-error-with-mongo-connectsession)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial can be old. The library API can be changed, I recommend you to use latest docs from https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo

Also if you can find it, you can install the same version of the connect-mongo used in the tutorial with `npm i connect-mongo@versionhere`

new usage:

```js
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');

app.use(session({
  secret: 'foo',
  store: MongoStore.create(options)
}));
```

and instead of `new MongoStore()`, seems you need to use `MongoStore.create(options)`